# Efficient way to insert 340 HTML Fields into a MS SQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a large HTML form containing 340 fields that I need entered into a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I'm trying to find a way to enter the data without meticulously writing out each variable in the PHP code (in $sql & $params). Maybe it's possible if the columns and variables had the same name.Here's a smaller version of the HTML form and the entire PHP coode. The SQL table currently only has the columns "Date" & "PartNumber".

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="test" action="http://10.0.0.252/test.php" method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="form283_1" value="" data-objref="61 0 R" title="Date:" name="Date" />
    <input type="text" tabindex="4" id="form339_1" value="" data-objref="62 0 R" title="PartNo." name="PartNo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="form366_1">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$serverName = "FILESERV1\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array(
  "UID" => "user",
  "PWD" => "Password",
  "Database" => "ipadforms"
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn === false) die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
echo "Successfully connected!";

if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors)=== true)
{
  $sql  = "INSERT INTO dbo.MF001 (Date,PartNumber) VALUES (?,?)";
  $params = array($post);

  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params);
  if( $stmt === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
  sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: Are the 340 fields just multiple instances of Date and PartNo, or are they all different things?

Comment: Field outputs are different. Fields range from radio buttons, to check boxes, to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an array of form field names -> table field names, then iterate it?

```
$fields = array('formfield1' => 'dbfield1', 'formfield2' => 'dbfield2', etc...);

foreach($fields as $formfield => $dbfield) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.FM001 ($dbfield) VALUES (?)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST[$formfield));
}
```

Note that the `$dbfield` has to be interpolated into the query string directly, since placeholders can only represent VALUES, not sql keywords or identifiers.

Comment: I tried that snippet of code,  but "$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);" throws errors: "Undefined variable" & "Call to a member function prepare() on null". Whats "$dbh" for?

Comment: it's just an example, in this case using PDO. you'll have to adjust for the sqlsrv_*() functions instead.

Comment: Its working now, but its inserting dbfield1 into row1, and dbfield2 into row2.

Comment: ah. if you want it all in the same record, then you'll have to build the query properly too `insert into ... ($dbfield1, $dbfield2, ...) values ($formfield1, $formfield2, etc...)`

Comment: So scrap the whole "$fields = array('formfield1' =>" and just keep it inline with "INSERT INTO"?

Comment: you'd still need the array, but instead of looping to do queries, you loop to build sql, then execute that one "cumulative" statement once. And if you make your form names match you db field names, you don't even really need the array, you could just do a `foreach($_POST as $field = $value)`-type thing.